# Pinta Program errror - troubleshooting linux programs

Tags: ubuntu, debug, libraries, pinta

I'm having an issue with the Pinta program, and i'd really like to use it. It's having an error, and truthfully by just looking at the "error log" im not able to figure out where to look. Perhaps, you could point me in the right direction and maybe give me some resources, websites, pdfs so forth for handling this in the future myself.

Appreciated. Here is the error:

```
free(): invalid pointer
Stacktrace:

  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) GLib.SList.g_free (intptr) <0x0005f>
  at GLib.ListBase.Empty () <0x0013c>
  at GLib.ListBase.Dispose (bool) <0x0000f>
  at GLib.ListBase.Finalize () <0x0001d>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_virtual_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00068>

Native stacktrace:

    /usr/bin/mono(+0xc8514) [0x55dbc8992514]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890) [0x7f2dfab9d890]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xc7) [0x7f2dfa5c0e97]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x141) [0x7f2dfa5c2801]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x89897) [0x7f2dfa60b897]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x9090a) [0x7f2dfa61290a]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4cc) [0x7f2dfa619e1c]
    [0x41ffbbb0]

Debug info from gdb:

[New LWP 15616]
[New LWP 15617]
[New LWP 15618]
[New LWP 15619]
[New LWP 15621]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
0x00007f2dfa696bf9 in __GI___poll (fds=0x55dbca1e8410, nfds=3, timeout=500) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
29  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c: No such file or directory.
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
* 1    Thread 0x7f2dfb759780 (LWP 15615) "Main" 0x00007f2dfa696bf9 in __GI___poll (fds=0x55dbca1e8410, nfds=3, timeout=500) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
  2    Thread 0x7f2df93ff700 (LWP 15616) "SGen worker" 0x00007f2dfab989f3 in futex_wait_cancelable (private=<optimized out>, expected=0, futex_word=0x55dbc8e85a08) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:88
  3    Thread 0x7f2df73d2700 (LWP 15617) "Finalizer" 0x00007f2dfab9d23a in __waitpid (pid=15630, stat_loc=0x7f2df73d086c, options=0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c:30
  4    Thread 0x7f2de8af1700 (LWP 15618) "gmain" 0x00007f2dfa696bf9 in __GI___poll (fds=0x55dbc9b271f0, nfds=2, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
  5    Thread 0x7f2de3fff700 (LWP 15619) "gdbus" 0x00007f2dfa696bf9 in __GI___poll (fds=0x55dbc9b60f50, nfds=3, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
  6    Thread 0x7f2de0a5c700 (LWP 15621) "pool" syscall () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/syscall.S:38

Thread 6 (Thread 0x7f2de0a5c700 (LWP 15621)):
#0  0x00007f2dfa69d839 in syscall () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/syscall.S:38
#1  0x00007f2df423e89a in g_cond_wait_until () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f2df41cb571 in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f2df41cbb2c in g_async_queue_timeout_pop () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007f2df4220c3e in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007f2df4220195 in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#6  0x00007f2dfab926db in start_thread (arg=0x7f2de0a5c700) at pthread_create.c:463
#7  0x00007f2dfa6a388f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 5 (Thread 0x7f2de3fff700 (LWP 15619)):
#0  0x00007f2dfa696bf9 in __GI___poll (fds=0x55dbc9b60f50, nfds=3, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007f2df41f85c9 in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f2df41f8962 in g_main_loop_run () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f2df4c490e6 in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007f2df4220195 in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007f2dfab926db in start_thread (arg=0x7f2de3fff700) at pthread_create.c:463
#6  0x00007f2dfa6a388f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 4 (Thread 0x7f2de8af1700 (LWP 15618)):
#0  0x00007f2dfa696bf9 in __GI___poll (fds=0x55dbc9b271f0, nfds=2, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007f2df41f85c9 in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f2df41f86dc in g_main_context_iteration () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f2df41f8721 in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007f2df4220195 in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007f2dfab926db in start_thread (arg=0x7f2de8af1700) at pthread_create.c:463
#6  0x00007f2dfa6a388f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7f2df73d2700 (LWP 15617)):
#0  0x00007f2dfab9d23a in __waitpid (pid=15630, stat_loc=0x7f2df73d086c, options=0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c:30
#1  0x000055dbc89925f0 in  ()
#2  0x00007f2dfab9d890 in <signal handler called> () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007f2dfa5c0e97 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#4  0x00007f2dfa5c2801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#5  0x00007f2dfa60b897 in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7f2dfa738b9a "%s\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181
#6  0x00007f2dfa61290a in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7f2dfa736d88 "free(): invalid pointer") at malloc.c:5350
#7  0x00007f2dfa619e1c in _int_free (have_lock=0, p=0x55dbca0bfb70, av=0x7f2dfa96dc40 <main_arena>) at malloc.c:4157
#8  0x00007f2dfa619e1c in __GI___libc_free (mem=0x55dbca0bfb80) at malloc.c:3124
#9  0x0000000041ffbbb0 in  ()
#10 0x000055dbca0bfb80 in  ()
#11 0x000055dbc97b40d0 in  ()
#12 0x000055dbc97b40d0 in  ()
#13 0x0000000000000000 in  ()

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f2df93ff700 (LWP 15616)):
#0  0x00007f2dfab989f3 in futex_wait_cancelable (private=<optimized out>, expected=0, futex_word=0x55dbc8e85a08) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:88
#1  0x00007f2dfab989f3 in __pthread_cond_wait_common (abstime=0x0, mutex=0x55dbc8e85a20, cond=0x55dbc8e859e0) at pthread_cond_wait.c:502
#2  0x00007f2dfab989f3 in __pthread_cond_wait (cond=0x55dbc8e859e0, mutex=0x55dbc8e85a20) at pthread_cond_wait.c:655
#3  0x000055dbc8b1a863 in  ()
#4  0x00007f2dfab926db in start_thread (arg=0x7f2df93ff700) at pthread_create.c:463
#5  0x00007f2dfa6a388f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f2dfb759780 (LWP 15615)):
#0  0x00007f2dfa696bf9 in __GI___poll (fds=0x55dbca1e8410, nfds=3, timeout=500) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007f2df41f85c9 in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f2df41f8962 in g_main_loop_run () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f2df63b3a37 in gtk_main () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
#4  0x0000000041fe43aa in  ()
#5  0x00007ffe639d5e50 in  ()
#6  0x00007ffe639d5e40 in  ()
#7  0x00007f2df9400950 in  ()
#8  0x00007f2df9400d60 in  ()
#9  0x00007f2df9400db0 in  ()
#10 0x000055dbc97e6d70 in  ()
#11 0x0000000041ebd6d0 in  ()
#12 0x00007ffe639d59d0 in  ()
#13 0x00007ffe639d5880 in  ()
#14 0x0000000041fe433c in  ()
#15 0x00007ffe639d59d0 in  ()
#16 0x0000000041ebd688 in  ()
#17 0x00007f2df94021f0 in  ()
#18 0x00007f2df9400788 in  ()
#19 0x00007f2df94021f0 in  ()
#20 0x00007f2dfb654130 in  ()
#21 0x00007f2df9400788 in  ()
#22 0x00007f2df94021f0 in  ()
#23 0x00007f2dfb650130 in  ()
#24 0x00007f2df9400788 in  ()
#25 0x00007f2df94021f0 in  ()
#26 0x00007f2dfb648130 in  ()
#27 0x00007f2df9400400 in  ()
#28 0x0000000000000000 in  ()

=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

Aborted (core dumped)
```